# Programmatic access to history (history.push etc) in react-router v5 outside of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I used to be able to pass history into React Router in <= v4:

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={history}>
   <App />
</Router>
```

**Edit:** My bad, I was using `Router` before not `BrowserRouter` which is needed for SSR. BrowserRouter might have never given this option. So it seems like the only solution is to split up the entry component and get history from `useHistory` hook and then pass it to `ApolloClient` or whatever.

Voting to close.

Comment: Can you provide more concrete information about `outside`? Like from reducers?

Comment: In say an HTTP fetch wrapper, or in this case in an apollo global link error handler - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error/

Comment: Makes sense. FAIK, one way would be to wrap the function (Error Handler) in a Hook and load it near the Router scope. Pass the hook factory the history object.

Comment: Hm yeah sadly I might need to do something like this, used to be nice and easy :|

Comment: Hooks have blurred the boundary of logic and view. I guess this goes in the spirit of hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my code can help you:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import qs from "qs";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

history.location = {
    ...history.location,
    query: qs.parse(history.location.search.substr(1)),
    state: {},
};
history.listen(() => {
    history.location = {
        ...history.location,
        query: qs.parse(history.location.search.substr(1)),
        state: history.location.state || {},
    };
});

const { go, goBack, push, replace } = history;

export { go, goBack, push, replace, getRedirectPath };
export default history;
```

And then use the exposed history in this file in react-router history prop. Now, you can use the exposed go or push functions outside of components or also inside.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, so using `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';` instead BrowserRouter helped!
Also, you need to import your history and pass as a prop to Router:
`<Router history={history}>`

Then history.push will case rerendering.

Answer (score -2):

you can try

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

createBrowserHistory().push("/login");
```

it work with "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2", seem it's not related to your question

Comment: Isn't this the same as using `window.history` since it isn't connected to react-routers instance it won't behave the same way?

Comment: that it's an working example from my project working code, it won't behave the same way

Comment: Edit: just tried and as expected it doesn't work since react-router is not using the same instance it doesn't re-render, so while the route changes nothing visual happens

Comment: sorry, I forget about version, I use "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2" in that example